# Concatenate 2 dataframes based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes, df_products_cp, like this one:

| product_id | version | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2 | CO |
| 1111 | 2 | BR |
| 1111 | 2 | MX |
| 2222 | 2 | CO |
| 3333 | 2 | CO |
| 3333 | 2 | MX |
| 4444 | 2 | CO |
| 4444 | 2 | BR |
| 4444 | 2 | MX |

and df_products_ec like this one:

| product_id | version | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 3 | CO |
| 1111 | 3 | MX |
| 2222 | 3 | CO |
| 4444 | 3 | CO |
| 4444 | 3 | BR |

How can I concatenate both so that I only get a single dataframe like this one, when the product_id/country combination is found in both dataframes?

| product_id | version | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2 | CO |
| 1111 | 3 | CO |
| 1111 | 2 | MX |
| 1111 | 3 | MX |
| 2222 | 2 | CO |
| 2222 | 3 | CO |
| 4444 | 2 | CO |
| 4444 | 3 | CO |
| 4444 | 2 | BR |
| 4444 | 3 | BR |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `merge` then `wide_to_long`

```
out = pd.wide_to_long(df1.merge(df2,on=['product_id','country']),
                      'version',
                      ['product_id','country'],
                      j = 'drop',
                      suffix = '\w+').reset_index().drop(['drop'],axis = 1)
Out[275]: 
   product_id country  version
0        1111      CO        2
1        1111      CO        3
2        1111      MX        2
3        1111      MX        3
4        2222      CO        2
5        2222      CO        3
6        4444      CO        2
7        4444      CO        3
8        4444      BR        2
9        4444      BR        3
```